# Swift - Cannot rename button before it is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, rename

I have problem with renaming a button. I have screen with some table view, where I have items e.g. - "first", "second", "third", ... I want to when I click on some item to get me on other screen, where will be button which will change the text based on which item I select. My problem is, when I click on first item e.g. "first", the Button has name "Button" not "first_detail" like I have in code bellow. I added Button like this:

```
@IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if names[myIndex] == "first" {
        sender.setTitle("first_detail", for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: self)
}
    if names[myIndex] == "second" {
        sender.setTitle("second_detail", for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
}
}
```

Thanks for advices.

Comment: If you are aiming to pass data from vc to another by using `performSegue`, then we should ask: Have you implemented `prepare(for:sender:)` method?

Answer (score 0):

You can set button title like this

```
var buttonTitle: String {
        didSet {
            self.yourbutton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

You can use

```
self.buttonTitle = "First"
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a outlet for button in VC and set the title for a button instead sender

```
@IBOutlet weak var itemButton: UIButton!
```

and check is it going inside any of the if condition

```
@IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if names[myIndex] == "first" {
        itemButton.setTitle("first_detail", for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: self)
    }
    if names[myIndex] == "second" {
        itemButton.setTitle("second_detail", for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: When i define `@IBOutlet weak var itemButton: UIButton!` and use in code in every if condition, the name still not showing. Button has still name "Button". Thanks

Comment: are you setting the button title in storyboard ??

Comment: you should set any default title for button, else you will default text as button

Comment: whats the names dictionary ??

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code isn't working is that an IBAction is triggered *after* the button is clicked. There is no way for the code to magically read your user's mind and change the text right before the button is clicked.

Create a property called 'buttonTitle' or something like that on your destination view controller. I prefer to avoid optionals if I can, so something like this would be what you want on the destination VC:

`var buttonTitle = ""`

If you're using a segue, then you need to override `prepare(for:sender:)` and set the buttonTitle property on the segue's `destination` view controller (this will require that you cast `destination` as your destination view controller's subclass).  Something like this example (I'm just calling your destination VC's class MyDestinationVC. Replace it with the correct name):

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? MyDestinationVC {
        destinationVC.buttonTitle = names[myIndex]
    }
}
```

Or, if you're pushing/presenting manually from code, then before you put it on screen, set that same `buttonTitle` property.

Then, in your destination view controller's `viewDidLoad()` method, set the button's title based on the buttonTitle property.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    myButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal)
}
```

Note: Other solutions that automatically update the button for you will cause crashes if called before `viewDidLoad()` because the views they're accessing will not have been initialized yet.

Comment: Thanks for explain. I progressed by your steps. In destination VC i put `var buttonTitle = ""`, after that i put to second VC `override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destinationVC = segue.destination as? recTableViewController {
            destinationVC.buttonTitle = names[myIndex]
        }
    }` and finally put this in destination VC `override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        testBtn.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: .normal) .... ` but now i have error message **Use of unresolved identifier 'testBtn'** in destination VC

Comment: No, you have to override prepare for segue in the view controller you’re *coming from*. You put the buttonTitle variable in the one you’re *going to*

Answer (score 0):

I have it these way:

1. I define `@IBOutlet weak var itemButton: UIButton!`
2. In action button i put only

   @IBAction func testBtn(_ sender: AnyObject) {
       if names[myIndex] == "first" {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "testSegue", sender: self)
       }
       if names[myIndex] == "second" {
           self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondSegue", sender: self)
       }
   }
3. To the second (target) VC i put these conditions

   if names[myIndex] == "first" {
       itemButton.setTitle("first_detail",
       for: UIControlState.normal)
   }
   if names[myIndex] == "second" {
       itemButton.setTitle("second_detail",
       for: UIControlState.normal)
   }
4. it works as I need